# How do I pull a GIF image from a webpage?

Tags: beautifulsoup, gif

I am trying to grab this image (https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/predictions/814day/814temp.new.gif)  but everything I have tried hasn't worked.

This is my latest attempt that didn't work....

[image]

Comment: Andrej`s answer should fix your issue - To improve your question and as best practice future, please provide your code as text not as image. Would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To save the GIF image from the webpage, use `requests.get(<URL>).content` directly. For example:

```py
import requests

url = (
    "https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/predictions/814day/814temp.new.gif"
)

with open("814temp.new.gif", "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

This saves the file `814temp.new.gif`